# how to Write a function that takes a list of strings as input, and returns the count of the number of strings

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, char

The strings lenght should be 2 or more and the first and the last chars of the string should be same.

I am trying to Write a function that takes a list of strings as input, and returns the count of the number of strings where The strings length should be 2 or more and the first and the last chars of the string should be same.

Comment: Please show us what you have done and errors you are getting

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
def special_strings_count(strings):
    return len([x for x in strings if len(x) > 1 and x[0] == x[-1]])

strings = [] # your list of strings
print special_strings_count(strings)
```